# Understanding the way a tangent space is defined on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Currently I'm working my way through Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry, and I'm confused by the way he has defined a tangent space - or specifically how the space of directional derivatives at a point $p \in M$, where $M$ is a differentiable manifold, is the same as the tangent space at $p$.

Carroll considers a $n$-manifold $M$, a co-ordinate chart $\phi:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n,$ a curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$, and a function $f: M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and the aforementioned point $p$. Then if $\lambda$ is the parameter along $\gamma$, and $x^{\mu}$ are the coordinates of the chart, we have
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}f=\frac{d}{d\lambda}(f\circ\gamma)$$
$$=\frac{d}{d\lambda}[(f\circ\phi^{-1})\circ(\phi\circ\gamma)]$$
$$=\frac{d(f\circ\phi^{-1})}{dx^{\mu}}\frac{d(f\circ\phi)^{\mu}}{d\lambda}$$
$$=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\partial_{\mu}f\space.$$
I'm a bit confused as to why the steps in the middle are needed (I'm a physics student, a Carroll's book is rigorous by physics standards) - if I try to bring it back to the more intuitive Euclidean space, if $\gamma$ and $f$ are maps to and from $\mathbb{R^3}$ respectively, then I would be happy to simply say
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}f  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial\lambda}$$
I'm getting the sense that this may be something to do with properly defining derivatives, but I'm really not sure, and this is really my first look at maths with any level of rigour beyond that needed to solve physics problems, so I'd appreciate some clarity here!

Answer (score 2):

The general idea with manifolds is that in order to do calculus operations on a manifold, you need to go back to the reference space, in this case Euclidean space. The functions $\phi$ are called homeomorphisms, but if that word is unfamiliar, the point is that they help translate between the manifold and the reference (Euclidean) space.

Notice that the line

$$=\frac{d}{d\lambda}[(f\circ\phi^{-1})\circ(\phi\circ\gamma)]$$

sets up a composition of two functions, each of which is goes from Euclidean space to Euclidean space. Given that, the next line

$$=\frac{d(f\circ\phi^{-1})}{dx^{\mu}}\frac{d(f\circ\phi)^{\mu}}{d\lambda}$$

is an application of the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is defined on a manifold, so for example to say that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}f  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial\lambda}$ you'd need to know what the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ means. That's why Carroll writes $\partial_{\mu}f$, as distinct from what you propose, and to use the standard calculus formula he goes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ via $\phi$, so that he gets a composition of functions between Euclidean spaces.